# How to re-use an existing task in sbt but with different settings

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

One of the use cases I have where I want to re-use an existing task is:
Publishing a locally built docker image to a custom registry.

It would be nice if I can just re-use: `Docker / publishLocal` but with other setting values.

Initially I thought something like this is possible:

```scala
Docker / publishMyReg := {
  dockerAlias := dockerAlias.value.withRegistryHost(Option("myregistry.foo.bar"))
  (Docker / publishLocal).value
}
```

I was surprised to see that there is no way to run a `Task` with different setting values or to have `Task` specific settings.

Whats the intended way of introducing such custom tasks?

I was looking at `Commmand` but it doesnt seem to do the job here. For the use case above I would like to be able to execute the following: `sbt my-project/docker:publishMyReg` which, as far as I know, is not possible with a `Command`.

Comment: Does anything [here](https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/package_configuration.html) help? It looks like you have two options: create a custom `scope` or create a duplicate project with custom configuration.

Comment: thanks @JarrodBaker that helps a lot! I actually already use the "sbt-parameters-and-build-environment" option